# Passing PHP Sessions

Tags: php

I am having problems passing session variables all of the sudden and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. See my test code below for createSession.php and passingSession.php. I can create the session ok on createSession.php but when I click the link to see if the session is passing to passingSession.php, the session is now empty.

Note: session_start() is the very first thing on each page. No leading white space of any kind.

createSession.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['aID'] =  time();

if($_SESSION['aID']==""){
    echo "Session is empty. There is a problem creating sessions";
}else{
    echo "Session = ".$_SESSION['aID']." There is no problem creating sessions.  <a href='passingSession.php'>Click Here</a> to see if sessions are passing ok.";   
}
```

passingSession.php

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['aID']==""){
    echo "Session is empty. There is a problem passing sessions.";
}else{
    echo "Session = ".$_SESSION['aID'].". Passing sessions is ok."; 
}
```

Comment: Turn error reporting up and make sure that cookies are enabled on the client. This should be pretty straight forward. also you could try to `echo session_name();` in both cases in case there is the config alteration due to .htaccess

Comment: consider doing a `print_r($_SESSION);` as well to see what _is_ there!

Comment: It would also be nice to rule out software updates, directory permissions, URL changes, etc.  As far as you know, did anything change?

Comment: as far as i know nothing has change BUT im on shared hosting so maybe (and im not an IT person :)  ).  I turned on errors and get this when creating the session Warning: Unknown: open(/var/php_sessions/sess_d770da94614fc29be4a0e5a2addca47c, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/php_sessions) in Unknown on line 0 and a NOTICE on the passing page

Comment: contact your hosting, only they can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use if($_SESSION['aID']=="") to test if a session exists but use [isset()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).
You are comparing your session variable to an empty string which is different from an unset variable.

Use something like this:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['aID'])){
    echo "Session is empty. There is a problem passing sessions.";
}else{
    echo "Session = ".$_SESSION['aID'].". Passing sessions is ok."; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a hosting configuration issue.  modifications made and sessions work fine again now.  Thank you Carlos Campderros